# What exactly this line means?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

**The location is the address of the memory word where the instruction is stored. It is important to differentiate it from the address part of the instruction itself**

I am reading Morris Mano's book on computer system architecture and I am getting more and more confused whenever the word **MEMORY** comes up and now here I don't exactly understand the difference being talked about here in statement 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose our hypothetical CPU has an instruction to load a register from an address in memory:

```
LOAD R<n>,<address>
```

Now let's suppose that your program contains an example of such an instruction, at address 0x1000, that loads register R3 from address 0x5678:

```
00001000   LOAD R3,0x5678
```

Then according to your quote, the location is 0x1000, and the address part of the instruction is 0x5678.